# index of the largest item in the ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

Let's take this ArrayList for instance [1, 3, 8, 9, 5, 7, 9].

I am working on getting the index of the largest item in the list and if the list has this item more than once, each time return a different index.

We can see that the largest item 9 is at the index 3 and at index 6.

Here is what I have been working on so far:

```
public static int getIndexOfLargest( List<Integer> list ){
    List<Integer> index = new ArrayList();
    if ( list == null || list.size() == 0 ) return -1; // null or empty
    Integer i=0, maxIndex=-1, max=null;
    for (Integer x : list) {
        if ((x!=null) && ((max==null) || (x>max))) {
            max = x;
            maxIndex = i;        
        }
        i++;
    }
    return maxIndex;
}
```

The above code only outputs the index 3. How do I update the code to get the list of indexes [3, 6]

Comment: So do you want to return a single index or all the indices having the max value?

Comment: If you want to get [3, 6] as the result, then should the return type of the method be `int`? What should it be?

Comment: @Eran I want to return all the indices having the max value.

Comment: @JBNizet I can have it as List<Integer>, but that is still not working

Comment: Start doing that. Now the the return type is `List<Integer>`, you must return a List<Integer> from the method, not an int. So, return `index`(which should really be named `maxIndices` or `result`) instead of returning maxIndex. And store all the max indices you find in the list. Of course, you'll need to clear the list if you find an element that is greater than the current max value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
public static List<Integer> getIndexOfLargest(List<Integer> list) {
    List<Integer> indicesOfLargest = new ArrayList();
    if (list == null || list.size() == 0)
        return indicesOfLargest; // null or empty
    Integer i = 0, max = null;
    for (Integer x : list) {
        if (x != null) {
            if (max == null || x > max) {
                indicesOfLargest.clear();
                max = x;
                indicesOfLargest.add(i);
            } else if (x == max) {
                indicesOfLargest.add(i);
            }
            i++;
        }
    }
    return indicesOfLargest;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use this method:

```
public static List<Integer> getIndexOfLargest( List<Integer> list ){
    if ( list == null || list.size() == 0 ) return new ArrayList <>(  ); // null or empty
    Integer i=0, max=null;
    for (Integer x : list) {
        if ((x!=null) && ((max==null) || (x>max))) {
            max = x;
        }
        i++;
    }

    i = 0;
    List<Integer> index = new ArrayList();
    for(Integer r : list){
        if(r == max){
            index.add( i );
        }
        i++;
    }
    return index;
}
```

and another option:

```
public static List<Integer> getIndexOfLargest( List<Integer> list ){

    if ( list == null || list.size() == 0 )
        return new ArrayList <>(  ); // null or empty

    return IntStream
            .range( 0, list.size() )
            .filter( i -> Objects.equals( list.get( i ), list.stream().max( Integer::compareTo ).get() ) )
            .boxed()
            .collect( Collectors.toList() );

}
```